# Can an Outlook add-in be tested on a remote machine without registry entries?

Tags: c#, registry, installation, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I've written solution that consists of outlook 2010 add-in which will serialize an email and moves it to a folder where the server app detects, deserializes it and takes over.

We're getting ready to do some preliminary testing on a remote machine that doesn't have Visual Studio installed

For the server app, I know I can avoid registering the dll's by making sure that they're are in the server executable directory...

Is there anyway, we can avoid messing with the registry for the outlook plug-in, to get this initial testing done.   According to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386106(v=vs.100).aspx "You must create a specific set of registry entries when you deploy add-ins"

Are there any tricks to get around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, Outlook reads the class name of your addin from the Outlook\Addins key in the registry, then uses that class name to create an instance of the COM object representing your addin.

There is no way to force Outlook to do anything else.